# How to check if date is a monday (PHP)

Tags: php, date, if-statement

how can I check if my date is a monday ?

Thats the date I want to check: 2020-04-20 00:00:00

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
if(date('D', $datum) === "Mon")
{
  echo "yes!";
}
```

Can someone please help me there, or show me an other way to check it ?

Comment: This works for me... Perhaps `$datum` wasn't correct. I answered with my function bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$date = new DateTimeImmutable('2020-04-20 00:00:00');

if ($date->format('N') == 1) {
    echo "yes!";
}
```

Or you can also do it this way:

```
$date = new DateTimeImmutable('2020-04-20 00:00:00');

if ($date->format('D') === 'Mon') {
    echo "yes!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my helper

```php
function is_monday($date) {
    return date('D', strtotime($date)) === 'Mon';
}
```